# vscode launch Cannot find module 'webpack-command'

Tags: visual-studio-code

vscode debugger encounter problem :Cannot find module 'webpack-command', i've installed webpack-cli global, here is my config

```js
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "node",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
      "args": ["--config", "./build/dev-server"]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error too. I was able to solve it with:

```sh
npm install --save-dev webpack-command
```